# Does running a synchronous method using Task.Run() make it asynchronous

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

Let's consider a class (This is not the class or code I'm using in my application, just trying to learn with this example)

```
class Person
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public int DeptId {get; set;}
    public string Department {get; set;}
}
```

Now let's assume I get a List of objects of the above class from my database. And if the volume is large, I would want a dictionary of Department Ids and the name of the department. Something in the form of a Dictionary<int,string>.

I have a method within the class as follows:

```
class Processing
{
        private Task<Dictionary<int,string>> MapDepartments(List<Person> people) => Task.Run(()=> people.GroupBy(p=>p.DeptId).ToDictionary(group=> group.Key, group=>group.First().Department;
}
```

And a separate method in my class

```
class Processing
{
    .
    .
    .
    Task DoStuff()
    {
        .
        .
        .
        //code execution to get data from the db
        var departmentDictTask = MapDepartments(people);
        .
        .
        .//some other code being executed, I don't need the department dictionary yet
        .
        .
        var dictionaryData = await departmentDictTask.ConfigureAwait(false);
    }
}
```

My questions are:

1. Here the method I've written to create a dictionary out of my List, does it run asynchronously?

- I'm thinking it does, because while debugging, I saw that it was in "Running" state for some time while my other code was running. Although I am not certain about whether this is indeed the case or not.

2. What's the difference between this and putting my dictionary logic in an asynchronous method?
3. Whatever I've implemented is this somewhat similar to having a .ToDictionaryAsync() method?

Comment: It puts it on another thread and allows it to run in parallel, which is async in a general sense but not the same as c# async, which doesn't require a separate thread. You should probably be using [ToDictionaryAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.queryableextensions.todictionaryasync?view=entity-framework-6.2.0) instead of `Task.Run(ToDictionary)`. Then you can just await it.

Comment: @JohnWu - does using ToDictionaryAsync do it in a more efficient way in terms of space/ speed? Can you provide some reference where I can comparatively read more on c# async vs what I have done?

Comment: Yes. It doesn't require a new thread so it avoids a lot of overhead. The only time you'd want to create a new thread is if you have an operation that is CPU-bound, and database operations are almost always I/O-bound. The I/O part of the O/S has its own threads so it makes no sense for c# to spin up a new thread just to wait for it.

Comment: @JohnWu: This is using a `List<>`, not Entity Framework. I'm not sure Entity Framework's `ToDictionaryAsync()` would even _work_ in this case, but if it did it wouldn't get the benefits you mention.

Comment: That said, I would seriously question the premise of this question. If you're getting a lot of Person objects out of the database, the time taken to load those objects out is going to dwarf the amount of time it takes to produce this dictionary. I'd say there's a high likelihood you're doing operations in-memory that should just be encoded in a query to the database.

Comment: @StriplingWarrior - This is not code that I am using in my application. I came across a scenario of where I have to turn a list of a large amount of data into a dictionary, and wanted to know if running code like this would be in parallel and provide me any benefits over running it synchronously.

Comment: @FaleinE: It _would_ be run in parallel. The only way to know whether you see benefits would be to measure its performance both ways. In my experience, there are relatively few cases where parallel processing produces meaningful benefits. In the places where an app really is not going fast enough, there are almost always other strategies that provide much more meaningful improvement. But this could be the exception. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Here the method I've written to create a dictionary out of my List, does it run asynchronously?

It's probably more accurate to say it runs *in parallel*. A separate thread is created to produce the result. If `people` isn't being used in a thread-safe way (e.g. it's a List that you're adding to in other threads), then you could end up with messy race conditions.

When people talk about "Asynchronous" code, there are two things they could mean.

1. Code that models an inherently asynchronous operation, like Disk or Network I/O, in a way that doesn't block a thread.
2. More broadly, any kind of operation that can complete independently from the current thread of operations.

What you've done matches the second definition, but not the first. If `people` were backed by a database round-trip, your code would still block a thread while that call completed: it would just be blocking a different thread than the one that calls `MapDepartments`.

> What's the difference between this and putting my dictionary logic in an asynchronous method?

Since you're pulling from an in-memory List, and all your operations are CPU-bound (not doing truly asynchronous operations), there would be no benefit to putting your logic in an `async` method, because there would be nothing for that method to `await`. Even though the method would say it's `async`, it would run *synchronously* to completion before returning a Task.

Assuming creating that dictionary really takes enough time to make it worth multi-threading, and assuming you're not modifying the underlying list before you `await` the Task, your current approach is better.

> Whatever I've implemented is this somewhat similar to having a .ToDictionaryAsync() method?

I mean, I guess you could write a `ToDictionaryAsync` method that just performs `ToDictionary` on a separate thread, but that's really not following the spirit of what `Async` means.

When a library like Entity Framework provides a `ToDictionaryAsync()` method, that's because they know there's going to be an actual database call that will actually be asynchronous, and they know how to make that happen in a non-blocking way without calling `ToDictionary()`. I would reserve `ToDictionaryAsync` for situations like that.

Comment: So, let's assume I have a request being made to an API from within my code, it would make sense to await it if the request were to take a lot of time since it is satisfying the first condition you mentioned. And it would also satisfy the second condition if I have certain operations that requires the data from that request.

And if I were to put that into a Task<Data> and await the task elsewhere, I would still run it on a new separate thread?

Comment: *"If `people` isn't being used in a thread-safe way (e.g. it's a List that you're adding to in other threads), then you could end up with messy race conditions."* -- I think that the technical term is "undefined behavior". :-)

Comment: @FaleinE: I'm not sure I fully understand your question, but I'll try my best: A REST API request satisfies both definitions of asynchronous. When you make an API request, you should use an Async method that already returns a Task. There should be no need to use `Task.Run`, and no new threads would need to be created. Depending on what kind of app you have (specifically its Task Scheduler), that might mean the _continuation_ of the Task happens on the original thread or a different one. Either way, other tasks are allowed to use the original thread while you're waiting for the API result.

Comment: If you store the `Task` for the API call, it's possible for many other threads to `await` it. While the task is still running, that would cause those other threads to be released for use by other Tasks. Once the task is complete, all the pending awaiters would complete, and any new `await`s on that Task will complete synchronously and immediately, on the same thread used before the `await`.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias: Yeah, both. The [race condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition) produces [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), which makes a mess. :-)

Comment: My understanding is that race conditions are more benign. A race condition can produce a small, predictable, range of behaviors. For example the `if (!concurrentCollection.Exists(x)) concurrentCollection.Add(x)` is a race condition and can result in the `x` not being unique in the collection. On the other hand when you have undefined behavior, like `nonThreadSafeList.Add(x)` on multiple threads, you have no clue about what might happen. It depends on so many factors, on the implementation details of so many pieces of software, that practically "anything" can happen.